# Why did Ubuntu 16.04 stop detecting external display's higher resolution? Or: What is the modeline for Samsung B1390n?

Tags: 16.04, xorg, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

## Problem

1366x768 disappeared from the resolution options for my external display. My display supports 1366x768 and the option used to be there. Now, the highest I can set it to is 1024x768.

So, how can I get my external display with 1366x768?

## How this is different from other questions already asked

The difference is that it used to work correctly!

I've been using 1366x768 on the external display on Ubuntu for a long time. However, after disconnecting it & reconnecting it while Ubuntu was working, it stopped giving me the 1366x768 option.

## Why other `randr` solutions weren't sufficient

- I've tried the solution of `cvt` and `xrandr`. However, `cvt` only gives me 1368x768, not 1366x768 & text is blurry.
- I also tried to look for modelines online. The best I could find is [this one](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1517805). However, there was a blank column on the right of the screen (and it's a hack, using another monitor's modeline).
- I tried to look in my Xorg logs to see if the modeline exists from old boots. However, the logs seem to be stopping at 2016 and I'm not sure I was using this display back then.
  I did try a modeline in the 2016 log but the result was strange patterns.

## Ways you could help me

1. If you know why the option disappeared although it used to be there and/or how to get it back to work automatically.
2. If you know the modeline for Samsung B1390N, resolution 1366x768.
3. If you know how to get `cvt` (or something else) to calculate modeline for 1366x768.
4. If you know how to get recent Xorg logs, or any logs that log the modelines. Reminder: My Ubuntu used to offer and work with 1366x768 for this external display.
5. If you know how to get the modeline Ubuntu needs from Windows 10. I might be able to connect this display to a Windows 10 machine of someone I know.

Any other solutions are appreciated, of course! :-)

## System info

- **OS:** Ubuntu 16.04
- **Display:** Samsung B1390N
- **Laptop:** Dell Inspiron n5110.

Comment: Can you check with another cable, just in case one of the wires in the cable got broken.

Comment: There's something I didn't mention: This used to happen but restarting solved it. That's why I'm doubtful the problem is with the VGA cable. Unfortunately, I currently don't have a spare one, but if I get one I'll probably get back with the results here.